# Drag and drop of rows in table in jsfiddle not working - angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I tried to have a drag and drop rows in my table - angularjs. My current code is

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
            <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>{{list}}
        <hr>
</div>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My controller code is

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

it is working well in http://jsfiddle.net/xfmh6ywm/ but not working with same code in http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zn9uz/. Similar to latter fiddle even in my website, I am unable to rearrange the rows.

Comment: I changed your fiddle to jQuery 1.8.3 with jQuery UI 1.9.2 and it works..

Answer (score -2):

Change the jQuery version from the left top corner dropdown to : jQuery 1.8.3
this would start working.

```
updated fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z4zn9uz/1/

Comment: Could you please specify reason for a DOWN VOTE.. :)

Comment: Because of that, I try to move first row from the top to the bottom, it is not working properly (Browser: Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m)

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work for me as well